# Terraform EKS Node Groups Private Subnet

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-eks

I'm trying to deploy a sandbox EKS cluster and node group to AWS with terraform and I'm struggling when it comes to the node groups.

My cluster is creating fine, but when attempting to apply the node groups I am getting the following error:

```
Ec2SubnetInvalidConfiguration: One or more Amazon EC2 Subnets of <subnet_id> for node group <node group name> does not automatically assign public IP addresses to instances launched into it.
```

Here's is the code in my module for creating the subgroup:

```
resource "aws_eks_node_group" "default" {
  count = var.create ? 1 : 0
  cluster_name    = local.eksclustername
  node_group_name = "${local.eksclustername}-ng"
  node_role_arn   = aws_iam_role.node[0].arn
  subnet_ids      = var.subnet_ids

  scaling_config {
    desired_size = 3
    max_size     = 6
    min_size     = 3
  }

  depends_on = [
    aws_iam_role_policy_attachment.AmazonEKSWorkerNodePolicy,
    aws_iam_role_policy_attachment.AmazonEKS_CNI_Policy,
    aws_iam_role_policy_attachment.AmazonEC2ContainerRegistryReadOnly,
    aws_eks_cluster.default
  ]
}
```

I am trying to deploy the node group into private subnets, which I am assuming is the source of this error. I know with EKSCTL you can deploy node groups to private subnets, but I am not sure how to get this working with terraform.

Am I missing a tag, variable of setting from my config?

Comment: This was an issue within Terraform until May when version `2.63.0` was released.

The issue is covered on [GitHub](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/issues/13071).  Can you try upgrading and see if this helps?

Comment: I'm using provider version 2.68.0 and this issue is still there. My subnets need setting to create set IPv4 on create, which by default is set to false as they are private subnets

Answer (score 3):

Maybe I'm late to answer this but it might help someone else as I just ran into the same issue. In my case I was trying to create the node group in a private subnet but that subnet was attached to the default route table that had IGW attached to it so EKS was considering it a public subnet and expecting a public IP being auto-assigned to new nodes.

Just make sure all the private subnets you are using does not have any IGW attached to it.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same message today.  In my case, the error message was misleading: the NAT gateway was not setup correctly in the private subnet, and instances couldn't access the internet.  I found this guide helpful for checking this:  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/nat-gateway-troubleshooting.html#nat-gateway-troubleshooting-no-internet-connection

In the unlikely case you made the exact same mistake as me, adding an `aws_route_table_association` in Terraform was what finally got things working.